# LMS retrieval/update lags 1 click behind

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

It seems that the component relying on the `URL` update doesn't get the correct `mediaId` from the `URL`. The first click gets the **`Something went wrong.... <template>`**, then each following click is 1 `mediaId` behind on `UI`.  I followed this [add/edit URL params](http://Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20edit%20my%20code%20to%20get%20the%20desired%20functionality?) guide online but am unable to fix the issue.

**Main problem** - when the user clicks a button, the page renders 1 mediaName behind. First click is always Something went wrong.... template, but the following clicks will follow in the order you click the buttons for movies or books.

I have tried putting the `this.navigateToNewPage();` before the publish message, but get the same thing as above. Is there a way to edit my code to get the desired functionality?

**HTML for Publisher**:

```
<template
for:each={bookOutput} for:item='book' key={book.bookId}>
<lightning-button title={book.bookName} 
 label={book.bookName} data-key={book.bookId} 
 onclick={handleBookClicked}></lightning-button>
</template>

for:each={movieOutput} for:item='movie' key={movie.movieId}>
<lightning-button title={movie.movieName} 
 label={movie.movieName} data-key={movie.movieId} 
 onclick={handleMovieClicked}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

**JS for Publisher**:

```
@api mediaList
handleMovieClicked(event){
     let selectedIdValue = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     this.newMediaId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     const message = {
          action:'media_info', 
          parameters: {mediaId: selectedIdValue, mediaList:this.mediaList}};
     publish(this.messageContext, navigationMessageChannel, message);
     this.navigateToNewPage();
}

handleBookClicked(event){
     let selectedIdValue = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     this.newMediaId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     const message = {
           action:'media_info', 
           parameters: {mediaId: selectedIdValue, mediaList: this.mediaList}};
     publish(this.messageContext, navigationMessageChannel, message);
     this.navigateToNewPage();
}
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
wiredPageReference(currentPageReference){
     if(currentPageReference) {
          this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
          this.mediaList = this.currentPageReference.state.c__mediaListId
     }
}

get newPageReference(){
     return Object.assign({}, this.currentPageReference, { 
      state: Object.assign({}, 
      this.currentPageReference.state, this.newPageReferenceUrlParams)});
}

get newPageReferenceUrlParams(){
     return {
          c__mediaId: this.newMediaId
     }
}

navigateToNewPage(){
     this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](
          this.newPageReference, true
)
}
```

**HTML for Receiver**:

```
<template if:true={mediaName}>
{mediaName}
</template>

<template if:false={mediaName}>
Something went wrong....
</template>
```

**JS for Receiver**:

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
wiredPageReference(currentPageReference){
     if(currentPageReference) {
          this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
          this.mediaName = this.currentPageReference.state.c__mediaId;
     }
}
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what the problem is. There are too many words and too much information here. Are you able to edit your question to clearly state the problem?  ie. when I click this, X isn't happening, or i'm getting this error.  If you can't state the problem that succinctly, the problem is too broad and you should look at narrowing down to a single problem.

Comment: Updated a bit, let me know if it is still hard to follow.

Comment: I think you need to focus on "First click is always error".  The rest of your story is just making noise, and if you're getting an error, why are you ignoring it and then reporting some weird extended behaviour?  My advice: Update this question to focus solely on that error.  If resolving that error doesn't resolve your broader process, narrow down to the next error or unexpected behaviour in a separate question.

Comment: ah okay, I mean the error is showing the "Something went wrong...." component. But I get what you mean, will start off there.

Comment: @NickCook I update the question after revisiting the code and retesting possible outcomes. Does this make more sense or make things clearer of what I am trying to fix?